# What is the pendant at the end of the Black Clover's 9th opening?

Tags: black-clover

At the end of the 9th opening of *Black Clover* (song: *RiGHT NOW*), Yuno's blue pendant shows up.

How is this related to Yuno if it is, and what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, SPOILER warning.

Now Yuno's pendant happens to be a magic stone. That pendant was the last magic stone the elves needed. So that's the reason it's shown at the opening.

MANGA SPOILER:

Yuno's relation with the pendant is explained in the manga. Yuno is actually the prince of the spade kingdom. His father is the overthrown king of the spade kingdom. A certain group attacked the king and his court so they can rule the kingdom. They wanted Yuno to be safe, so their butler put Yuno at the church, sacrificing his his own life. The magic stone belonged to the king, and that's the reason he gave it to Yuno.